# ASP.NET Core debugging not working for OnGetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My page model calls a method that executes a query.

```
// Retrieve financials
var details = await (from detail in dbContext.StorageDetails
                        where (detail.ArrivalDate != null && detail.ArrivalDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
                        (detail.DepartureDate == null || detail.DepartureDate >= dateRange.StartDate)) ||
                        (detail.TakeOrPayStartDate != null && detail.TakeOrPayStartDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
                        (detail.TakeOrPayEndDate == null || detail.TakeOrPayEndDate >= dateRange.StartDate))
                        orderby detail.Location.City, detail.Location.State, detail.ArrivalDate
                        select new
                        {
                            Location = new
                            {
                                Id = detail.LocationId,
                                detail.Location.Name,
                                detail.Location.City,
                                detail.Location.State
                            },
                            detail.RailcarNumber,
                            detail.TakeOrPayId,
                            detail.TakeOrPayStartDate,
                            detail.TakeOrPayEndDate,
                            detail.ArrivalDate,
                            detail.DepartureDate,
                            detail.CherryPickDate,
                            detail.DailyStorageRate,
                            detail.SwitchInRate,
                            detail.SwitchOutRate,
                            detail.CherryPickRate,
                            detail.DailyStorageCost,
                            detail.SwitchInCost,
                            detail.SwitchOutCost,
                            detail.CherryPickCost,
                        })
                        .ToListAsync();
```

I set a breakpoint at the start of this query. When I step over it my code stops in my page's CSHTML file, complaining that the variable that would've held the result of this query is `null`!

If instead of stepping over this query, I step into it, I find myself stepping through `ApplicationDbContact.OnModelCreating()`.

I thought `OnModelCreating()` was just used for generating the database schema. So this doesn't make any sense at all to me.

Is there anyone that can see something here, or have I completely broke ASP.NET Core? How would anyone begin to troubleshoot something like this?

This is my page model handler. The query above is in `helper.GetFinancialsByLocation()`.

```
public async void OnGetAsync()
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
    DateRange = new DateRange
    {
        StartDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1),
    };
    DateRange.EndDate = DateRange.StartDate.AddMonths(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);

    try
    {
        FinancialsHelper helper = new FinancialsHelper();
        FinancialsLocations = await helper.GetFinancialsByLocation(DbContext, DateRange);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Here's my startup.cs.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the database configured? How are you obtaining dbContext? Do you have *any* other async code that you aren't awaiting, either in your model or your startup?

Comment: It's just a local database. The code is running `OnGetAsync()`. It's sets a data range, creates an object and then calls this method. I don't think I've changed anything in startup for this project.

Comment: `OnModelCreating` should be called the first time the context is obtained from dependency injection. Wtihout that metadata, EF wouldn't know how to generate sql. Which should be before your page model is created. Assuming there's nothing weird going on there. So we need to see your startup and page model constructor...

Comment: Right, because the framework couldn't await anything, since you never returned a task. Hence my initial comment about not awaiting something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) you should be using:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
```

rather than:

```
public async void OnGetAsync()
```